# Log url response with js

Tags: javascript

I have this js function that posts to a url and I need to record the response that the site returns.  I am wondering what the best way to do this. Here is a sample of a url string and how the post response works.  I am needing to make a log file to keep track of the responses of the pings we send. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample url string.

```
https://www.arcamax.com/cgi-bin/autosub?email=test@email.com&scextcode=bigredtestping&source=4679



function loadIframePixels(e)
{
    if(inEmailpixelArray('arcamax')) {
        document.getElementById('ifrm').src = 'https://www.arcamax.com/cgi-bin/autosub?email=' + e + '&fname=&lname=&listid.1=15&listid.2=52&source=' + arcmxid + '&ipaddr=' + _localip + '&ts=' + Date.now() + '&leadid=LEADID&scextcode=' + _subid;
    }else {
        _can_redir = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. You need to make a log on the client, or on the server?

Comment: Ideally, to a log file on my site.

Comment: This looks like it's making a get request, and it's doing it by setting the src of an <iframe>. An issue with that is you can't read the contents of an iframe for security reasons. You might want to look into making the requests someway else, such as the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), but even then there's not guarantee that it'll work due to [CORS restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: Thank you. If I did not use the iframe and used the sample url what would be the best way to get the response?